# Accessing a rectangle's value?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio

```
myObject.rect.X = 100
```

myObject has a property called rect (which is a Rectangle). During runtime I will want to chage the X position of such rectangle, but I am given this error:

*Expression is a value and therefore cannot be the target of an assignment.*

Then, how am I supposed to change such values?

Comment: Are you sure that is the line producing the error?  You might need to supply more code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Expression Is a value and therefore cannot be the target of an assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/681464/expression-is-a-value-and-therefore-cannot-be-the-target-of-an-assignment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are talking about `System.Drawing.Rectangle` here.  `Rectangle` is a value type (`Structure` in VB.NET), so when you access it via the `myObject.rect` property, you get a copy of it locally.  Since you have a copy of the values instead of a reference to the instance, you cannot update it.

If you want to change `myObject`'s `Rectangle` property, you can update `myObject` to refer to a newly constructed `Rectangle` with values you desire.  For example:

```
    Dim myObject As MyObject = New MyObject()

    ' Prints 0
    Console.WriteLine(myObject.rect.X)

    ' Refer to a new rectangle with X=100 and all other values kept the same
    myObject.rect = New Rectangle(
        100,
        myObject.rect.Y,
        myObject.rect.Width,
        myObject.rect.Height
    )

    ' Prints 100
    Console.WriteLine(myObject.rect.X)
```