# Expression is a value and therefore cannot be the target of an assignment. VB

Tags: vb.net, vba

The Code:

```
If Play.Location.X > (Mob.Location.X) Then
Mob.Location.X = (+("1"))
End If
```

"Mob.Location.X = (+("1"))" Is getting the error "Expression is a value and therefore cannot be the target of an assignment"

Does anyone know how to fix this?

P.S Sorry for my poor English, im from Sweden.

Comment: @dotNET http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.point_properties(v=vs.110).aspx (Gets or Sets) Am I overlooking something?

Comment: @Steve: Yes. Wondering at the upvotes though. :)

Comment: The problem here is the the LHS expression (`Mob.Location.X`) is a value, which cannot be assigned to.

Comment: Is this code actually for VB.NET or Visual Basic for Applications(MS Office)?  Big difference and will affect the answer.

Comment: @dotNET You're right, this doesn't work since `Point` is a value type.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Expression Is a value and therefore cannot be the target of an assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/681464/expression-is-a-value-and-therefore-cannot-be-the-target-of-an-assignment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to increment the X component:

```
Mob.Location = new Point(Mob.Location.X + 1, Mob.Location.Y)
```

Else:

```
Mob.Location = new Point(Mob.Location.X, Mob.Location.Y + 1)
```